# How to allow auto-imports="true" when we use Nhibernate 3.2's mapping by code?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have to use an HQL query in my project and I've an error : "entity is not mapped".

When I read [nHibernate HQL - entity is not mapped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6577428/nhibernate-hql-entity-is-not-mapped) or [nHibernate HQL - entity is not mapped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6577428/nhibernate-hql-entity-is-not-mapped) (or other web site) I can read that I have to use auto-import="true" on each class.

```
<hibernate-mapping
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 namespace="BusinessObjets" assembly="BusinessObjects"
 xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" auto-import="true"> ...
```

How can we set up this auto imports when we use mapping by code with nhibernate 3.2 ?

I use that code to load the mapping :

```
var mapper = new ModelMapper();
mapper.AddMappings(typeof(Repository).Assembly.GetTypes());
return mapper.CompileMappingForAllExplicitlyAddedEntities();
```

Regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't set it in mapping-by-code directly, but you can modify `HbmMapping` object returned from `CompileMappingForAllExplicitlyAddedEntities` method, before you pass it to the `Configuration` object:

```
mapping.autoimport = true;
```

Comment: thank you. it's hard to find all the stuff with mapping by code

Comment: Saved me an hour of digging through NHibernate code - thanks!